# the select query is not executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have written a code for login authentication using select query in ASP.NET C# in Visual studio 2012. The partial code is

```
String conn = "Data Source=Srinidhi-PC\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=model;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
    con.Open();
    String query ="select * FROM [original] WHERE firstname='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and password='" + TextBox2.Text + "'"; 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
    SqlDataReader reader =  cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows == true)
        Response.Redirect("redirectpage.aspx");
    else
        Response.Write("Login Failure");
```

But every time, the system responses only **"Login Failure"**. What is the issue here?

`ExecudeReader` returns the records that match the condition. As far as the query is concerned, I wrote it for practice. I will add parameters in my original code.

Comment: You should NEVER, EVER use in-line SQL, because it opens you up to SQL Injection attacks and also for the potential of data with spaces and/or invalid characters. Try `TextBox1.Text.Trim()` and `TextBox2.Text.Trim()` and see if that helps. I am assuming that `original` is the actual name of the database table that you want to select from. Does the query work in SQL Server if you hard-code the values in?

Comment: ' or 1=1 --that should get you going :)

Comment: (reader.HasRows == true)s can be shortened to (reader.HasRows).  And you don't even need a a reader just a count(star).  Start with a select count(start) from [original]

Comment: Nope the query doesnt give me the answer even if i hardcode the vlues in the string :(

Comment: But my question was with no (zero) values do you get anything?  Just a test on if you are hitting the table and the tables has any values.  Just a Select star from [original].

Comment: Yes... i get the full table

Comment: When the help text says to edit and improve your question, it does not mean changing it into a completely different question. That still counts as circumventing your question ban, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot going on here, it's tough to disentangle.

Most importantly what if someone types `';(drop table [original])` into TextBox1?  This is called [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), it's bad, and if you are learning to be a programmer you need to learn what it is, and how to avoid it.

Lucky for you it's a solved problem and you can find a information about it all over the web, even here on SO: [SQL Injection attack prevention: where do I start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162862/sql-injection-attack-prevention-where-do-i-start)

[image: Classic XKCD]
from http://xkcd.com/327/

Next, if `reader.HasRows == false` that doesn't mean there was a login failure, it means that the query returned 0 rows.  If you were unable to login, then the call to `con.Open()` would throw an exception, so, your problem is that actually your query isn't returning data.

Also, if you are just counting rows to perform a redirect, you probably want to use a [`count`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) query, which will execute faster and use less server resources.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your code as below

```
var query = "select COUNT(*) FROM [original] WHERE [firstname]=@firstname and [password]=@password";
var conn = "Data Source=Srinidhi-PC\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=model;Integrated Security=True";
using (var con = new SqlConnection(conn))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);
    con.Open();
    var result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (result > 0)
        Response.Redirect("redirectpage.aspx");
    else
        Response.Write("Login Failure....");

}
```