# Removing Last character of a string c#

Tags: c#, string, trim

I am perplexed that the code I wrote is not doing the action I wanted to.

My aim : Removing the last character of a string (string build using string builder).

My approach :

```
  string toTrim = STR.ToString(); //here i have "INSERT INTO [dbo].[RCCMrec] ('ANI' , 'DNIS' , 'Date' , 'Time' , 'ConnId' , 'UUID' , 'EmployeeId' , 'AgentDN' , "

 toTrim = toTrim.Remove(toTrim.Length - 1);
    // here I STILL have "//here i have "INSERT INTO [dbo].[RCCMrec] ('ANI' , 'DNIS' , 'Date' , 'Time' , 'ConnId' , 'UUID' , 'EmployeeId' , 'AgentDN' , ""
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, you might not want to build your SQL query like that. Check out [this answer on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9162904/1020861).

Comment: I think you can safely mark this question as answered ... (hopefully with the most upvoted one ;p )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra space at the end of the string ...
so you can either use `-2`, or make sure you don't have the space at the end  by doing

```
string toTrim = STR.ToString().Trim();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Substring` instead:

```
toTrim = toTrim.Substring(0, toTrim.Length - 1);
```

Working example:

```
var input = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuxyz";
Console.WriteLine(input);
input = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1);
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

prints

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuxy
```

**But looks like your problem is not connected to `string.Remove` method. Following code works just fine and prints the same results:**

```
var input = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuxyz";
Console.WriteLine(input);
input = input.Remove(input.Length - 1);
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of using Substring here over Remove? The intent is less obvious and the performance is probably equal or worse.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault `Remove(int)` uses `Substring(int, int)` internally, so the second one will perform a little bit better (because of one method call less in the stack trace and two parameter checks from `Remove` method).

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I found where I went wrong.
While building the string in the substring I had accidentally inserted a SPACE after the COMMA ,as

```
 foreach (string COLUMNS in values)
                {
                    STR.Append("'");
                    STR.Append(COLUMNS);
                    STR.Append("' , "); //here is mistake
                }
                //Removing the last COMMA( , ) 
                string toTrim = STR.ToString();
              string lol= toTrim.Substring(0, toTrim.Length - 1);
```

I so wanted to remove thus the codes were removing the SPACE and not the comma.
I rectified to

```
 foreach (string COLUMNS in values)
                {
                    STR.Append("'");
                    STR.Append(COLUMNS);
                    STR.Append("' ,"); //corrected
                }
                //Removing the last COMMA( , ) 
                string toTrim = STR.ToString();
              string lol= toTrim.Substring(0, toTrim.Length - 1);
```

Thank you for your help you all.

Comment: that's what i've said in my answer above :) ... I'd change the naming to : `string Trimmed = STR.ToString().Trim().Substring(0,STR.Length -1);`