# SQL in booking system

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, postgresql

I'm building an asp.net application using C# and postgreSQL database. The application is a booking system for a doctors office.

I have the following table for booking appointments:

[image]

I have the following table for times:

[image]

There is a relation between column times in both tables (time in tbl_appointment is a foreign key to time in tbl_times).

In the application I have a drop down list like below. The user first choose doctor, then choose date and then click on the drop down list to choose a time. The drop down list with times is loaded from the database tbl_times.

[image]

Now my question:
How can I write SQL to only load the times that does not have an appointment?
If the user first choose Dr D and then date 2014-04-23, then in the drop down list I want to load all the times from tbl_times EXCEPT 08:00 and 10:00.

**Updated:**
My problem is how to exclude the records.
I have tried this SQL (of course I do not to write the values):

```
SELECT time
FROM tbl_times
WHERE time NOT IN (
  SELECT time
  FROM tbl_appointment
  Where doctor = 'Dr D' AND date = '2014-04-23'
 )
```

Comment: Of course not. My problem is that I don't know how to exclude a record in a SQL-statement. See my updated post for sql.

Comment: Try a left join and a where appointments.ID is null

Answer (score 2):

You're making life hard for yourself because you don't have a Doctors table. I would also have a single DateTime column instead of a Date and a Time. My suggestion would be to do:

```
select t.DateTime, d.Name from times t
cross join doctors d
left join Appointments a on t.DateTime = a.DateTime and d.DoctorID = a.DoctorID
where a.ID is null
```

This will give you a list of all the Doctors' free appointments.

As I mentioned in my comment you need to read up on [SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162904/352176). As it stands your code is very vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out the solution. This is how I did:

```
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT time FROM tbl_time WHERE time NOT IN (SELECT time FROM tbl_appointment Where doctor = '" + doc + "' AND date = '" + date + "')", conn);  
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ddTime.Items.Add(DateTime.Parse(dr["time"]ToString()).ToShortTimeString());
            }
```

Comment: A couple of things, 1st and most important your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. This is very important. 'doc' and 'date' need to be parameters. 2nd I don't believe you've actually answered the question. In your original you asked about finding free times? Here you're passing in a specific time to match? 3rd, if it comes out as a DateTime keep it as a DateTime, don't convert ToString() until you really need to. This will help you do things like calculate the time until appointments in the future