# execution of stored procedures is not running

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I have problems when calling stored procedures filters customer data.
table:

```
ID   : CS-001, CS-002, CS-003  
Nama : xxxxxx, xxxxxx, xxxxxx
```

functions in C #

```
public DataTable pilihCustomer(string id)
{
    classKoneksi = new koneksi();
    sql = "call PilihCustomer(" + id + ")";
    tabel = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        classKoneksi.koneksiBuka();
        komand = new MySqlCommand(sql, classKoneksi.konek);
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(komand);
        adapter.Fill(tabel);
    }
    catch (Exception) {}

    classKoneksi.koneksiTutup();
    return tabel;
}
```

and I call this

```
private void editToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (LvCustomer.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {            
        string id = LvCustomer.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        FCustomer f2 = new FCustomer();
        DATA_ACCES.Acces_Customer baca = new DATA_ACCES.Acces_Customer();
        tabel = baca.pilihCustomer(id);
        string  nama = "", npwp = "", tlp = "", fax = "", email="", kontak="";
        foreach (DataRow kolom in tabel.Rows)
        {
            nama = kolom["nama perusahaan"].ToString();
            npwp = kolom["npwp"].ToString();
            tlp = kolom["telepon"].ToString();
            fax = kolom["faxmile"].ToString();
            email = kolom["email"].ToString();
            kontak = kolom["kontak"].ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select an item before assigning a value.");
    }
}
```

Functions above can be run if the table as

```
ID   : 101, 102, 103  
Nama : xxxxxx, xxxxxx, xxxxxx
```

Comment: Do you define anywhere that kommand is a stored procedure?? e.g   komand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: What problem are you having? Error messages? No data? Something else?

Comment: @apomene well, the sql is `"call PilihCustomer(" + id + ")";` - which has a range of other problems, but does at least call the proc - indirectly

Comment: @Deri: warning - please be aware that your code is susceptible to SQL injection, a serious and readily exploited risk that is trivially avoided by correct parameterization; you should *not* concatenate input values into SQL.... *ever*

Comment: The `catch (Exception) { }` makes me suspect that it is already trying **really really hard** to tell you what is going wrong, but you're just ignoring it and carrying on...

Comment: @MarcGravell I still do not understand the sql injection.
and I also want to learn. I think to avoid sql injection then we have to understand first the sql injection.

how to inject this my code.

Comment: @DeriTriadiPutra for example, if I looked for `id` of `1) drop table Accounts --`

Answer (score 0):

The `id` parameter is a string so it needs to be surrounded with single quotes so change the line that generates the SQL to this:

```
sql = "call PilihCustomer('" + id + "')";
```

However, as other commenters have mentioned your code is extremely unsafe and you should be using parameterised queries.

Comment: thank you for the explanation.
for this code I've managed to use single quotes following the advice DavidG,

but I want to learn again how to avoid sql injection.

how to resolve the issue.
is there anything that would give me an example

Comment: sql injection .... ???? make a headache, hehehe ...
for now, I think the code that is simple to learn first

Comment: It's easier than you think and I 100% advise you loot at it now before you continue.

Comment: I do not know where to start to learn.
because I learned just rely on the help of the internet.
please help .....

Comment: The internet is a good place to find the information! I just Googled sql injection and it showed [this SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162862/sql-injection-attack-prevention-where-do-i-start). Also, don't forget to accept answers and upvote where you have been helped.