# SQL select parameter contains apostrophe

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters

I have issue with `productName` parameter which contains the string `Acreditors buye's something` and in this case I need just to check does productname and SKU exists in db.

I am getting error

> Incorrect syntax near 's'.
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''."

I tried some escape  char stuff, and also using like but nothings works.

This is my code:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + toDB + ".dbo.Products WHERE Name like '" + productName.Replace("'","\'") + "' and SKU='" + newSKU+"'";

SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cs);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, c);
c.Open();
object o = (object)command.ExecuteScalar();
c.Close();
```

THIS  IS ONLY SAMPLE  I AM AWARE OF SQL INJECTIONS THANKS

THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR HELPING ME:
THIS IS CODE THAT ACTUALLY WORKS WELL:

```
        string commandText = "SELECT * FROM " + toDB + ".dbo.Product WHERE Name= @prodName and SKU=@sku;";

        using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, c);
            command.Parameters.Add("@prodName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters["@prodName"].Value = productName;

            command.Parameters.Add("@sku", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters["@sku"].Value = newsku;

            c.Open();
            object o = (object)command.ExecuteScalar();
            c.Close();
            if (o != null)
                result = true;
        }
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Instead of trying to escape it just make the apostrophe a double apostrophe '' ... sql reads that as a single.

Comment: You are aware of sql injection but you are unaware that the same pattern that avoids sql injection would remove also your problem with apostrophes

Comment: Also using a SELECT * just to check for the record presence is not really a good practice. I would try to use IF EXISTS in your query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

THANKS ONE MORE TIME TO ALL AND THIS IS WORKING CODE:

```
    string commandText = "SELECT * FROM " + toDB + ".dbo.Product WHERE Name= @prodName and SKU=@sku;";

        using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, c);
            command.Parameters.Add("@prodName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters["@prodName"].Value = productName;

            command.Parameters.Add("@sku", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters["@sku"].Value = newsku;

            c.Open();
            object o = (object)command.ExecuteScalar();
            c.Close();
            if (o != null)
                result = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use parameters for your query, then you will not need to escape special characters like:

```
using (SqlCommandBuilder sqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder())
{
    toDB = sqlCommandBuilder.QuoteIdentifier(toDB);
}


string query = "SELECT * FROM " + toDB + ".dbo.Products WHERE Name like @productName and SKU = @SKU";

using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cs))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, c))
{
    c.Open();
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@productName", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = productName });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SKU", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = SKU });
    //or command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productName", productName);

    object o = (object)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Since you are using `toDB` *(may be from user input)* you should escape that, Use [`SqlCommandBuilder.QuoteIdentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.quoteidentifier(v=vs.110).aspx), since you can't pass parameters for table names/column names etc.

One more thing is to use `using` statement with those object which implements `IDisposable` interface. In case of `SqlConnection`, enclosing the statement in `using` will ensure that the connection gets closed at the end of scope. In the above case, the connection will close after executing the command, even in case of an exception.

String concatenation to create SQL queries is open to SQL injection. Read more about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and see [SQL Injection attack prevention: where do I start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162862/sql-injection-attack-prevention-where-do-i-start)

Answer (score 3):

For SQL you need to use a double single quote.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + toDB + ".dbo.Products WHERE Name like '" + productName.Replace("'","''") + "' and SKU='" + newSKU+"'";
```

*However* that is subject to SQL injection attacks.  Instead use parameters (as a bonus you don't need to escape the apostrophe):

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + toDB + ".dbo.Products WHERE Name like @product and SKU= @sku";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product",productName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sku",newSKU);
```

Comment: You should really show an example with sql-parameters since that would not only fix this issue implicitly but also the mentioned sql-injection vulnerabilty.

Comment: There are so many examples available I didn't think it merited expanding the scope of the question.

Comment: By not showing the correct way you are unintentionally promoting this bad habit to kick to OP and future readers.

Comment: `product` and `sku` not sure who gave the `+2` UpVote..but Parameters in Sql Server expect the `@` you should read up on the following [Using SQL Server Input/Output Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zafes24f(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @DJKRAZE, you don't actually need the `@` prefix for SqlParamter (you do need it in the query of course). It is confusing and undocumented but I recently had to maintain some code which consistently didn't use the @ prefix and it worked fine.

Comment: I agree `adrianm` I should have stated that this would be more of a syle / conding standard that you see from a greater majority of the developers but I do agree with you