# SQL Like Operator (single quotation)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Lets take a string as userinput.

WHEN :

```
string sUserInput = "Jonson"
```

THEN :

SQL Like Operator :

```
"SELECT * FROM Table_User WHERE UeserName LIKE ('%" + sUserInput + "%')
```

means `"SELECT * FROM Table_User WHERE UeserName LIKE ('%Jonson%')`

WHEN :

```
string sUserInput = " 'N/M' Jonson" ;
```

Then In LIKE part sql gets error, 
because It becomes `('%'N/M' Jonson%').`

It gets error because it get '' (single quotation) within ''(single quotation). How can I solve it?

Comment: This is what bind variables are for. Not only are you less vulnerable to SQL injection but all of this stuff is done for you. What language are you using? The less complicated answer is to escape the single quote, which means adding 2 instead of 1.

Comment: No, I am using C# @Ben

Comment: For what you should be doing so you're not vulnerable see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6547986/458741, http://stackoverflow.com/q/9162862/458741, http://stackoverflow.com/q/14376473/458741 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5468425/458741

Comment: Just I need how to get single quotation within single quotation in a query?

Comment: I know, the duplicate question tells you how, I'd recommend doing it properly though, hence the additional links.