# Trying to insert values into database from ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I said it clear enough, I am trying to insert values into a database via C# and it is not working with the code I have. No need to put my question on hold. I thought this could be a place where beginners could find help, not get looked down upon by people!!!

I'm trying to insert values into a database via asp.net and C#. I have a basic survey form with a combination of text boxes and radio buttons. When I run the code to insert the values the radio button value gets inserted fine. I'm having trouble with the text box values.

The ASP.NET markup:

```
Date of Flight&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="flightdate" runat="server" /><br />
Time of Flight&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="flightTime" runat="server" /><br />
Flight Number&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="flightNum" runat="server" /><br />
Flight Destination&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="flightDest" runat="server" /><br />

<strong>Friendliness of customer staff: </strong>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="question1" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="No Opinion"                                                                    Selected="True">No Opinion</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Poor">Poor</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Fair">Fair</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Good">Good</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Excellent">Excellent</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And the C# code behind:

```
  string flightDate = Request.QueryString["flightDate"];
  string flightTime = Request.QueryString["flightTime"];
  string flightNum = Request.QueryString["flightNum"];
  string flightDest = Request.QueryString["flightDest"];
  string selectedFriend = "";
  string selectedSpace = "";
  string selectedComfort = "";
  string selectedCleanliness = "";
  string selectedNoise = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < question1.Items.Count; ++i)
  {
      if (question1.Items[i].Selected)
      {
               selectedFriend = question1.Items[i].Value;
      }
  }

  SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IDEA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True");

  try
  {
      dbConnection.Open();
      dbConnection.ChangeDatabase("airlineSurvey");

      string results = "INSERT INTO results(flightDate, flightTime, flightNumber, flightDestination, friendliness) " + "VALUES('" + flightDate + "', '" + flightTime + "', '" + flightNum + "', '" + flightDest + "', '" + selectedFriend + "')";

      SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(results, dbConnection);
      sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

      regMessage.Text = "<p>Thank you for your feedback!</p>";
  }
  catch (SqlException exception)
  {
      Response.Write("<p>Error code " + exception.Number + ": " + exception.Message + "</p>");
    }

    dbConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: What's happening with the text boxes? You don't really say what the problem is.

Comment: Beginners can find help here, but they should read [ask] before asking poor questions which will be put on hold (until you correct the question). Then the question can be reopened. You never said what "problem" you were having with the text boxes. Note that you got good answers, even though you did not ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting empty values is that you should be using `Request.Form` instead of `Request.QueryString`.

However, since your text boxes are already server side controls,
then you do not even need to use `Request.Form` as you can use simply:

```
var flightDate = this.flightdate.Text;
var flightTime = this.flightTime.Text;
var flightNum = this.flightNum.Text;
var flightDest = this.flightDest.Text;
```

Also, the way you build `SQL` query is very bad - you are enabling SQL injection.

Please take a look at the: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162904/461810

Comment: This worked, thanks. I realize the coding is not secure. I am just in the beginning stages of learning C#

Answer (score 1):

You should access the values of TextBoxes via Text Property:

```
string flightDate = flightDate.Text;
string flightTime = flightTime.Text;
string flightNum = flightNum.Text;
string flightDest = flightDest.Text;
```

but there is still room for improvement:
for dates, you should use Calendar control, for destination field would be nice to chose from ComboBox control, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This worked the best:

```
var flightDate = this.flightdate.Text;
var flightTime = this.flightTime.Text;
var flightNum = this.flightNum.Text;
var flightDest = this.flightDest.Text;
```