# in this int o =sc.executenonquery(); is giving error "incorrect syntax near ' ' system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception" what todo?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection ("Data Source=SAGAR\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ClinicDb;Integrated Security=True");
    con .Open();
    SqlCommand sc=new SqlCommand ("insert into Patient_Details values('"+textBox1 +",'"+textBox2 +",'"+textBox3 +",'"+textBox4 +",'"+textBox5 +");",con );

    int  o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    try
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0 || textBox2.Text.Length == 0 || textBox3.Text.Length == 0 || textBox4.Text.Length == 0 || textBox5.Text.Length == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Fill all the fields");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Values are Inserted successfully...!");
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
        textBox5.Clear();

    }
    catch (Exception) { MessageBox.Show("something went wrong...Try Again"); }

    MessageBox.Show(o + "saved");
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: i have correct all that n now its showing error in int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery(); error as sqlexpection was unhandled

Comment: check for datatypes in your table and query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing both `.Text` off the end of `textBox1` etc and you are not quoting the items correctly (you are missing lots of `'`'s). Change:

```
SqlCommand sc=new SqlCommand ("insert into Patient_Details values('"+textBox1 +",'"+textBox2 +",'"+textBox3 +",'"+textBox4 +",'"+textBox5 +");",con );
```

to:

```
SqlCommand sc=new SqlCommand ("insert into Patient_Details values('"+ textBox1.Text +"','"+ textBox2.Text +"','"+ textBox3.Text +"','"+ textBox4.Text +"','"+ textBox5.Text +"');",con );
```

Then, go to http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp and learn about SQL injection attacks and change your code to prevent this happening. [See this question for plenty of advice on how to achieve that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162862/sql-injection-attack-prevention-where-do-i-start).

Comment: I'm guessing they also need to access the .Text property of the textboxes. And also, why is the execute not inside the try catch, which is where validation is occurring on something that could already have been inserted into the db?

Comment: I haven't downvoted but i guess that the reason was that you mention that he shouldn't use this code but then you show him how to "fix" it. On that way they will never learn to write secure code. The fact that it's accepted shows me that it's also the way he used and that he won't use sql parameters.

Answer (score 4):

There is a missing apostrophe here:

```
'"+textBox2 +"
```

But don't use string concatenation to build your queries but parameterized queries. Otherwise you are open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Also use the `using` statement to dispose any unmanaged resources/close the connection.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SAGAR\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ClinicDb;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    con.Open();

    using (var sc = new SqlCommand("insert into Patient_Details values(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4);", con))
    {
        sc.Parameters.Add("@Col1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
        sc.Parameters.Add("@Col2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        // ..
        int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Use the correct datatype in the first place, I have shown an example for `varchar` and `int`.

Comment: i have correct all that n now its showing error in int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery(); error as sqlexpection was unhandled

Comment: @SagarS: what is the `InnerException` message? What have you used as sql-query, what is your C# code, what are the columns in your table(incl. datatype)?

Answer (score -1):

Use Text property of textboxes.

```
textbox1.Text// in the query.
SqlCommand sc=new SqlCommand ("insert into Patient_Details values('"+textBox1.Text +"','"+textBox2.Text +"','"+textBox3.Text +"','"+textBox4.Text +"','"+textBox5.Text +"');",con );
and of course the missing apostrphe and use parametrized query.
```

Comment: i have correct all that n now its showing error in  int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();     error as sqlexpection was unhandled

Comment: provide the exception message.

Comment: downvoted??? sir please can u give a correct code or syntax to add data in my databse using windows form ???

Comment: provide the table structure (datatypes of the column) so that I can write code.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Patient_Details] (
    [Patient Id] INT           NOT NULL,
    [Name]       VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [Age]        INT           NULL,
    [Gender]     VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Contact No] INT           NULL,
    [Address]    TEXT          NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Patient_Details] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Patient Id] ASC)
);                          //sir is there any mistake in using datatype please tell me??

Comment: you should use nvarchar(max), varchar(max) instead of text datatype.
[info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187993.aspx) and  for contact no do not use int. Max size of int is 2,147,483,647 which is insufficient to store contact details. i guess same query should work after changing datatype of contact column.

Comment: k.sir i will try thnx for helping me

Comment: sir its showing sqlexception unhandled while saving the data from form.?

Comment: What is the inner exception message you are getting? you can get it in exception details or you can put in try catch and get the message.

Comment: int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery(); //getting error in this line like conversion error